# Hyperledger Fabric - Could not start peer - "Could not find genesis.yaml"

Tags: centos, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, peer

I wanted to natively build the code, so I downloaded the code and the `make` was successful for `peer` and `membersrvc`. I built it on a CentOS VM running on VirtualBox.
Now, when I attempt to run peer, it throws up the below error; unfortunately, I could not find a relevant documentation that could help me resolve this.

```
$ ./peer node start
2017-03-09 05:12:33.017 EST [common/configtx/test] 1 -> CRIT 001 Could not find genesis.yaml, try setting PEER_CFG_PATH, ORDERER_CFG_PATH, or GOPATH correctly
panic: Could not find genesis.yaml, try setting PEER_CFG_PATH, ORDERER_CFG_PATH, or GOPATH correctly

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging.(*Logger).Panicf(0xc4201de930, 0xccb574, 0x5d, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go-dev/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging/logger.go:194 +0x11e
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/configtx/test.init.1()
        /root/go-dev/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/configtx/test/helper.go:72 +0x3c7
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/configtx/test.init()
        /root/go-dev/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/configtx/test/helper.go:113 +0xb1
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.init()
        /root/go-dev/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/join.go:140 +0x91
main.init()
        /root/go-dev/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:148 +0x82
```

I could start membersrvc without errors.
Any clue?
Can someone point me to a relevant documentation on "setting PEER_CFG_PATH, ORDERER_CFG_PATH". I tried setting environment variables rather than updating a configuration file - which did not help.

Thanks!

Comment: A defect has been raised for the error, can be found on [JIRA](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2739)

Comment: Hyperledger v0.6 is an old architecture and has been completely rewritten. You won't get bug fixes or support on this version. v1.0 has now been released. You should look to move to the latest version.